Family of symmetric unimodal distributions where kurtosis is *inversely* related to peakedness?
The paper "On the Meaning and Use of Kurtosis" was published by DeCarlo in the prestigious journal Psychological Methods in 1997. It is highly cited (>1500 cites, 129 "highly influential"), and people still refer to it frequently in the literature and web content.  However, the first sentence of the abstract states:

For symmetric unimodal distributions, positive kurtosis indicates
heavy tails and peakedness relative to the normal distribution,
whereas negative kurtosis indicates light tails and flatness.

This statement is incorrect as regards peakedness and flatness, and has no doubt contributed to the remarkable persistence of the "peakedness/flatness" misinterpretation, despite more recent research that thoroughly debunks the notion that kurtosis measures anything about the peakedness or flatness of a distribution, symmetric and unimodal or otherwise.
It would help to dispel the myth if a family of symmetric unimodal distributions were given where the distributions became more peaked as kurtosis decreases, and more flat-topped as kurtosis increases.
(Edit: Since "peakedness" is ill-defined, for the purposes of this exercise it can be operationalized as the height of the distribution of the standardized variable.)
A simple example of such a symmetric unimodal family is $\{F_1, F_2\}$, where $F_1$ and $F_2$ are given on the Wikipedia page: $F_1$ is an equal mixture of the beta distribution with parameters $0.5$ and $1$ with its reflection about $0.0$, and $F_2$ is a mixture of a uniform between $−1$ and $1$ with a $T(4.0000001)$ Student's t-distribution, with mixing probabilities $0.999$ and $0.001$. In this family, the higher kurtosis distribution is low and appears perfectly flat-topped, whereas the lower kurtosis (and "platykurtic') distribution is infinitely peaked.
However, it would be interesting to describe a more traditional infinite family $F_{\theta}$, where $\theta$ varies continuously, within which kurtosis ranges from "platykurtic" ($<3$) to infinite, and where the distributions (all symmetric and unimodal) range from infinitely peaked to nearly flat-topped as kurtosis ranges from its minimum to infinity.
Suggestions?

There are many possible solutions.  I am reluctant to say anything more without (i) some clarification of "more traditional" and (ii) a quantitative definition of "peakedness:" although that has an intuitive meaning, we need something better.  One very general concept of "peakedness" is purely local: it characterizes the sharpness of the PDF at the mode but asserts nothing about its shape at any other point.  (Indeed, even "infinitely peaked" is vague, because there can be varying degrees of "infinite.")  I suspect you have a narrower concept in mind.  What would it be?

BTW, the Irwin-Hall distribution is worth consideration.  Its parameter (a natural number) can be extended to any positive real value.  For small values it has a sharp peak and low kurtosis, becoming smoother and higher in kurtosis as the parameter increases.

Yes, peakedness is ill-defined. I'll settle for "height", assuming constant std dev. Irwin-hall is interesting, but cannot have kurtosis approaching infinity.

Edited to define "peakedness," at least for the purpose of the post.

The height alone is problematic, because it doesn't transform in the same way as the kurtosis, which is scale-invariant.  Perhaps you intended "height at the mode of the standardized version of the distribution"?

Right, that's what the edit states.
